# Are haskell channels `Control.Concurrent.Chan` safe for multiple readers/producers?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, atomic

I need to put together a concurrent system with one shared `Control.Concurrent.Chan` between threads. There will be only one consumer and many producers.
Looking at the [`Chan` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html) I did not see any warning about the number of consumers and producers that may work on the same channel, and the source code seems to be using the default "safe" accessors for `MVar`s, therefore I think it should be safe to assume that there shouldn't be limitations but I'm not sure.
So, my question is... do you know whether haskell channels are safe (in general) for multiple readers and producers, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are safe for any number of threads. They are a simple MVar-based linked list.  The design trade-offs allow for dupChan which help in the opposite case of broadcasting to multiple readers.

The Chan is so simple it does not count the number of items inside, nor does it have an upper bound.  So if the producers outrun the consumer then the Chan will become very very large.  If this is a problem then you could pair the Chan with a (MVar Int). and have the producers and consumers modify the running total of items in the Chan.

Comment: Good, thanks. The absence of an upper bound is not a problem in my case because every thread will send one and only one message, upon completion. It's a simple structure I'm going to use to make the main thread wait for N messages (if N is the number of threads) from the channel before proceeding.

Comment: A counted barrier like this looks like a quantity semaphore, you might replace the Chan's linked-list length with MSem or MSemN in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SafeSemaphore using an initial quantity of (1-N).

Comment: I did not know about semaphores in the haskell platform, thank you very much for pointing it out. I'll replace channels with them for sure.

Comment: Of course, if you do add a separate MVar variable you are writing code with locks with all its drawbacks.  You may consider using `TChan` and `TVar` instead (i.e., use software transactional memory).

Comment: I find STM is not a performance boost compared to a simple MVar.  If the STM alternative is locking a big subset of many MVars then _perhaps_ STM will perform better.  If the STM is allowing many concurrent readers (optimistically) and the occasional write then _perhaps_ STM will perform better.  But STM _is_ way simpler to use properly.

Comment: @Riccardo Look at the [BoundChan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BoundedChan) and [stm-chans](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-chans) packages for solutions that already count the number of elements in the channel.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Thanks, I'll keep them in mind for the future but as Chris suggested I already applied the simpler `MSemN` solution to my code.